# JMS Performance: BytesMessage vs ObjectMessage

Tags: java, serialization, jms

In terms of JMS performance, I have read that ObjectMessage should be avoided for performance reasons.

How bad are ObjectMessage performance-wise?
Should I serialize to a BytesMessage and manually deserialize?

Comment: Have you run into a problem?  Have you benchmarked the two?  Is this really the slowest part of your application?

Comment: No, I haven't actually benchmarked.  I'm rewriting a significant amount of code and didn't want to head down one method only to realize that there's a problem with it.  Wanted to do my research first.

I came across this 9 year old thread and haven't seen anything newer: http://www.mail-archive.com/jboss-development@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07681.html  

Was hoping to hear something more authoritative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The performance overhead of `ObjectMessage` is because of the `java.io` serialization process. If you do that yourself and use `ByteMessage`, you're just doing what JMS would do itself, and you'll be no better off.

If you need to send java objects via JMS, you should use `ObjectMessage`, that's what the API provides. This allows the container to make some optimizations, e.g. JBoss will use its own proprietary serialization protocol, which is considerably faster than the standard `java.io` one.

Comment: I've been looking at Hessian Serialization.  It seems to serializes objects to about 1/2 the space as Java Serialization.  I haven't done any real tests yet, but it seems like using this+BytesMessage could be advantageous over ObjectMessage in this case.

Comment: I'd probably go with JBoss Serialization over Hessian/Burlap, but in principle yes, there are better alternatives to standard serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Example using Jackson Smile data format which can be up to 50% faster AND smaller than JDK serialization, so BytesMessage in this case will beat ObjectMessage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.smile.SmileGenerator;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;

import javax.jms.BytesMessage;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;

public class BytesMessageCreator<T> implements MessageCreator
{
  public static final ObjectMapper
    MAPPER=new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory().disable(SmileGenerator.Feature.ENCODE_BINARY_AS_7BIT));

  final String messageId;
  final T pojo;

  public BytesMessageCreator(final T pojo)
  {
    messageId=null;
    this.pojo=pojo;
  }

  public BytesMessageCreator(final String messageId, final T pojo)
  {
    this.messageId=messageId;
    this.pojo=pojo;
  }

  @Override
  public Message createMessage(final Session session) throws JMSException
  {
    try{
      final BytesMessage message=session.createBytesMessage();
      message.writeBytes(MAPPER.writeValueAsBytes(pojo));
      if(messageId != null){
        message.setJMSMessageID(messageId);
      }
      return message;
    } catch(Exception e){
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

}
```